# APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-console

I have an android app which I am trying to upload to Google Play Console.

After analyzing the apk, I can find the same .so files in x86, arm64-v8a and armeabi-v7a folders.

I don't have a x86_64 though.

But still, when I upload my apk to google play console, I get this error:

> APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only
>   have 32-bit native code

I have followed the documentation to add

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

in my build.gradle file, but that doesn't the structure of the apk.

This is how my analyzed apk looks like:

[image: This is how my analyzed apk looks like]

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Agora SDK unfortunately does not support x86_64, which means you'll need to drop support for x86 altogether to be able to upload to the Play Console. Remove 'x86' and 'x86_64' from the list of abiFilters.

At the same time, I would recommend reaching our to the SDK developers to ask them to add support for it so you don't lose on potential users.